# Hiding records in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

What I want to do is to hide the records/data from the datatable so that, by default, it will show "no data available in table". But, when the user uses the search function, it will display the matching records. If there is no data in the search and in my column filters, there will be no data to be displayed. In short, I just want my records to not appear as default. The records should only appear when searched.

Setting deferLoading: 0 doesn't load the data at first, but when I delete the info from my search bar, the records still show.

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "../assets/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "sRowSelect": "multi",
            "aButtons": [
                "select_all",
                "select_none",
                {
                    "sExtends":    "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Advance Tools",
                    "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf","print" ]
                }
            ]
        },
        bProcessing: true,
        bServerSide: true,
        bRegex:true,
        "oLanguage" : {"sZeroRecords": "", "sEmptyTable": ""},
        deferLoading: 0,
        sAjaxSource: "server_processing.php"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom filter to hide the rows, and then reset / set this filter when the user do a search / clears the search box.

```
function hideRowsFilter() {
  $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
     return false
  })
  dataTable.fnDraw();
}  
function clearFilter() {
  $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.pop();
  dataTable.fnDraw();  
}
```

after you have initialised the dataTable, set the filter

```
hideRowsFilter();
```

reset / set the filter according to user input

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').on('keyup', function() {
   if (this.value != '' ) {
      clearFilter();
   } else {
      hideRowsFilter();
   }
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zusz9a0n/**

The demo and the code above is using 1.9.x, something tells me you are using 1.9.x - but it will work with 1.10.x as well.

Comment: Hi david! thanks!
how should i implement this to my code ? 

sAjaxSource: "server_processing.php"

 });

I've put your code here

});

I used your code there but it nothing happens, i'm having errors when i put it anywhere else.

Comment: @chrisjai32 - paste the code you have made into the fiddle, press update so it get a new url and post it here, perhaps I can tell what is wrong.

Comment: @chrisjai32 - you had a typo in `.dataTable_filter` missing `s`, then it works (if you turn the `sAjaxSource` not used in the example off) and turn `bServerSide` off (you are not performing serverside filtering and so on) - **http://jsfiddle.net/zusz9a0n/4/**  of course, in your project where you have `server_processing.php` present you should use the `sAjaxSource`. Hope it helps.

Comment: i did what you did but it still doesnt work for me.

here's my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/zusz9a0n/11/

Am i doing something wrong ? or is the problem coming from `server_processing.php`?